# How can I intercept openGL function calls in Android framework?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-source

I know I can get openGL function calls by ADB(adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo) and Android Device Monitor. But I want to get them in a lower level(framework or driver...?). What should I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a profiler tool from the vendor of the GPU used by the phone :

- Mali: [Mali Graphics Debugger](http://malideveloper.arm.com/resources/tools/mali-graphics-debugger/)
- Adreno: [Adreno GPU Profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/adreno-gpu-profiler) or the newer [SnapDragon Profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-profiler)
- Nvidia: [Nvidia PerfHUD](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfhud-es)

My preference goes to Adreno GPU profiler and PerfHUD, in my experience they are the most stable and they do not need to root the device.

Those tools are really usefull, you can:

- view all GL commands, shaders, textures etc.
- edit shaders while app is running
- get interesting performance metrics (ex: finding the heaviest draw calls)
- and many more things

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I quite appreciate for that. I had used some similar tools for tracing before you replied me.  But what I really want is to catch them in smartphones without any outside methods. I want to use machine learning in real time to achieve some functions and the function calls are inputs.